# Empty Multi Dimensional Array Initializing omitting pointer

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to initialize empty arrays in Javascript the same empty arrays are intialized in php?

```
$blah = array("0" => "wew", "1" => "fdafa");

foreach ($blah as $blat => $val) {
              $arr[] = $val
              $arr[$blah][] = 1; 
}
```

Or just

```
foreach ($blah as $blat => $val) {
                  $arr[] = $val
    }
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand with the context of your code. Are you able to clarify?

Comment: What is `$arr[$blah][] = 1;` supposed to do in PHP, using an associative array as a key confuses me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to declare the `var` and initialize it to `[]` before pushing items to it.

```
var blah = {"0":"wew", "1":"fdafa"}; // an object, not an array

var arr = [];
var obj = {}
for (var blat in blah) {
    var val = blah[blat];
    arr.push(val);
    obj[blat] = 1; 
}
```